# Selecting multiple items in a ListBox

Tags: .net, winforms

I am using Listbox for display a list. I need select all above item if an item is selected and also do not allow unseleted above items.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should help:

```
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

            listBox1.SelectionMode = SelectionMode.MultiSimple;
            listBox1.MouseDown += listBox1_MouseDown;
}

private void listBox1_MouseDown(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
        {
            int selectedItem = listBox1.IndexFromPoint(e.Location);

            listBox1.SelectedIndices.Clear();
            for (int i = 0; i <= selectedItem; i++)
            {
                listBox1.SelectedIndices.Add(i);
            }
        }
```